# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when I'm modding the index by the array length

Tags: java, arrays, hashtable, indexoutofboundsexception

```
public class OpenHashTable {
    int[] backingArr;
    /*  Valid is a boolean array that keeps track of whether the hashcode in
        the backingArr has been "deleted" or not. False == deleted */
    boolean[] valid;
    int numElements;
    double loadFactor;
    double maxLoad;

    public OpenHashTable() {
        this(0.8);
    }

    public OpenHashTable(double maxLoad) {
        this(null, maxLoad);
    }

    public OpenHashTable(int[] hashCodes, double maxLoad) {
        this.maxLoad = maxLoad <= 1.0 ? maxLoad : 0.8; /* An open hashtable
        cannot exceed a loadfactor of 1.0 */
        this.loadFactor = 0.0;
        int numElements = 0;

        if (hashCodes != null) {
            /*  We create a new backing array so that the load factor is
                initally 1/2 of the max load factor. This was arbitrarily
                chosen. */
            backingArr = new int[(int) (maxLoad / 2 * hashCodes.length)];
            valid = new boolean[backingArr.length];
            add(hashCodes);
        } else {
            backingArr = new int[10];
            valid = new boolean[backingArr.length];
        }
    }

    public boolean add(int hashcode) {
        if (loadFactor >= maxLoad) {
            resize();
        }

        int index = Math.abs(hashcode % backingArr.length);
        if (!valid[index]) {
            /*  If valid at the given index is false, then the backingArray is
                "empty" at that spot, so we add the hashcode to the table,
                update the loadFactor, and return true to show that the code was
                added */
            backingArr[index] = hashcode;
            valid[index] = true;

            numElements++;
            loadFactor = (double) numElements / backingArr.length;
            // if (loadFactor >= maxLoad) {
            //     resize();
            // }

            return true;
        } else {
            // System.out.printf("%d,%d;", index, backingArr.length);
            while (valid[index % backingArr.length]
                && backingArr[index % backingArr.length] != hashcode) {
                /*  Search the table for the first open spot, or stop when you
                    find the hashcode in the table. If the current index is the
                    same as hashcode, then we stop before incrementing index.
                    Otherwise, we keep searching for an empty spot */
                index++;
            }
            if (backingArr[index % backingArr.length] != hashcode) {
                backingArr[index % backingArr.length] = hashcode;
                valid[index % backingArr.length] = true;

                numElements++;
                loadFactor = (double) numElements / backingArr.length;

                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
                /*  The given hashcode already existed in the table, so the data
                    was not added */
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean add(int[] hashcodes) {
        boolean success = true;
        for (int x: hashcodes) {
            success = success && add(x);
            /*  Once adding a hashcode fails once, success will always be
                false */
        }

        return success;
        /*  This will only return true if all data was added succesfully */
    }

    public void resize() {
        int[] oldBackingArr = backingArr;
        backingArr = new int[oldBackingArr.length * 2];
        loadFactor = (double) numElements / backingArr.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < backingArr.length; i++) {
            if (valid[i]) { // Don't add deleted elements
                add(oldBackingArr[i]);
            }
        }
        /*  The new load factor should be automatically updated when we call
            add */
    }

    public String toString() {
        String returned = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < backingArr.length; i++) {
            returned += "[" + i + "]: ";
            if (valid[i]) {
                returned += backingArr[i] + " ";
            } else {
                returned += "- ";
            }
        }
        return returned;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class OpenHashTest {
    private static OpenHashTable hashTable = new OpenHashTable();
    private static String[] data = {"Emma", "Olivia", "Sophia", "Isabella", "Ava", "Mia",
                    "Emily", "Abigail", "Madison", "Charlotte", "Harper",
                    "Sofia", "Avery", "Elizabeth", "Amelia", "Evelyn", "Ella",
                    "Chloe", "Victoria", "Aubrey", "Grace", "Zoey", "Natalie",
                    "Addison", "Lillian", "Brooklyn", "Lily", "Hannah", "Layla",
                    "Scarlet"};
    public static void main(String... args) {
        int[] hashcodes = new int[data.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            hashcodes[i] = data[i].hashCode();
        }

        hashTable.add(hashcodes);
        System.out.println(hashTable);
    }
}
```

So I'm currently writing a linear probing open hash table for a school course, and I've provided my hash table code, and the code I'm using to test it. I am getting the most baffling error:

> java : Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
>
> at OpenHashTable.add(OpenHashTable.java:60)
>
> at OpenHashTable.resize(OpenHashTable.java:103)
>
> at OpenHashTable.add(OpenHashTable.java:39)
>
> at OpenHashTable.add(OpenHashTable.java:87)
>
> at OpenHashTest.main(OpenHashTest.java:15)

I don't understand how I can be getting an index out of bounds when I'm modding by the array size. Also, when I check to see what size the array is at the time of this error, it tells me 20, which means 10 should not cause an index out of bounds... What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems to be in `resize`.

You iterate over the indices of the new (larger) backing array, while accessing elements of the old (smaller) backing array :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < backingArr.length; i++) {
        if (valid[i]) { // Don't add deleted elements
            add(oldBackingArr[i]);
        }
    }
```

You should probably change the loop's condition to `i < oldBackingArr.length`.

EDIT : As Thomas commented, you should also resize the `valid` array when you resize the `backingArr` array.

Comment: That is the first problem. The second problem is that the `valid` array does not get resized.

Comment: Many thanks to both of you. I find it slightly frustrating it was something so simple, but I'm happy to be able to move on.